# List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, overflow

I am trying to use list comprehension and the power of the nested function to return a list of all Dates being Friday 13 within a given year in the form (dd/mm/yyyy). I am however having very little luck with nested loops, I would appreciate any assistance I could get with resolving this issue.

The previously created function to be used is seen as:

```
def day_of_week11(d, m, y):
    # Write your code here
    day_names =['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
    if m < 3:
        y -= 1
        m += 12
    m -= 2
    yd = y % 100
    yc = y // 100
    day = (d + ((13*m-1)//5) + yd + yd//4 + yc//4 - 2*yc) % 7
    day=(math.ceil(day))
    if 2>day>=1:
        return day_names[0]
    elif 3>day>=2:
        return day_names[1]
    elif 4>day>=3:
        return day_names[2]
    elif 5>day>=4:
        return day_names[3]
    elif 6>day>=5:
        return day_names[4]
    elif 7>day>=6:
        return day_names[5]
    else:
        return day_names[6]
```

#The function I am attempting to write now is:

```
def not_lucky (yr):
    def day_of_week11(d, m, y):
    # Write your code here
        i=(d, m, y)
    return len([i for i in range(12) if day_of_week11(d, m, y)(yr,i+1,13)==4])
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please provide example input and expected output and the actual output you are getting.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Possible inputs would be seen below.

>>> unlucky(2010)

[(13, 8, 2010)]

>>> unlucky(2009)

[(13, 2, 2009), (13, 3, 2009), (13, 11, 2009)]

There would be two ranges in this comprehension, (1,31) and one for month (1,12). I know I would use the day_of_week11 to check if a given date is Friday, but not sure how to also check if it is equal to the 13

Answer (score 1):

```py
from datetime import timedelta, date

given_year=2021

start_date = date(given_year, 1, 1)
end_date = date(given_year+1, 1, 1)

list_of_friday_the_thirteenth=[single_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") for single_date in (start_date + timedelta(n) for n in range((end_date-start_date).days)) if single_date.weekday()==4 and single_date.day==13 ]

print(list_of_friday_the_thirteenth)
```

Comment: updated to format the dates as dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Importing the timedelta does work perfectly. Thank you, wanted to make use of the day_of_week function though

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension would be too complicated in this case.
Possible solution is following:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def thirteenth_fridays(year):
    d = date(year, 1, 1)
    if d.weekday() <= 4:
        days = 4 - d.weekday()
    else:
        days = 11 - d.weekday()
    d += timedelta(days)
    while d.year == year:
        if d.day == 13:
            yield d.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        d += timedelta(days = 7)
        

for d in thirteenth_fridays(2024):
    print(d)
```

Prints

```
13/09/2024
13/12/2024
```